# Is it possible to find the intersection of 3 sets in c++ in a single line?

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have 3 sets A,B,C. I will need to find
Union (intersection(A,B), intersection(B,C), intersection(A,C) )

(A ∩ B) ∪ (B ∩ C) ∪ (A ∩ C) in set notation.

Is it possible to convert it into code without needing to declare 4 more sets.

```
#include <set> 
using namespace std;
set<int> set1, set2, set3;
set1.insert(1);
set1.insert(2);
set2.insert(2);
set2.insert(3);
set3.insert(1);
set3.insert(4);
// set1 = {1,2} , set2 = {2,3}, set3 = {1,4}
```

Here is the normal way using set_intersection() and set_union()

```
set<int> res1, res2,res3;
set_intersection(set1.begin(), set1.end(), set2.begin(), set2.end(), inserter(res1,res1.begin()));
set_intersection(set2.begin(), set2.end(), set3.begin(), set3.end(), inserter(res2,res2.begin()));
set_intersection(set1.begin(), set1.end(), set3.begin(), set3.end(), inserter(res3,res3.begin()));
set<int> result;
set_union(res1.begin(), res1.end(), res2.begin(), res2.end(), inserter(result, result.begin())
.
.
.
```

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it instead. Is anyone able to provide me with some suggestions?

Comment: Does writing your own function count as "more elegant"? It's not surprising to run into a bit of awkwardness when using tools for a purpose that goes beyond their design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it'd be an extremely long line that would piss off anyone who would try to read it.

As for a more "elegant" approach, you should split up what you're trying to do into functions:

```
    vector <int> getIntersection(vector < vector <int> > &sets) 
{ 
    vector <int> result;  // To store the reaultant set 
    int smallSetInd = 0;  // Initialize index of smallest set 
    int minSize = sets[0].size(); // Initialize size of smallest set 
  
    // sort all the sets, and also find the smallest set 
    for (int i = 1 ; i < sets.size() ; i++) 
    { 
        // sort this set 
        sort(sets[i].begin(), sets[i].end()); 
  
        // update minSize, if needed 
        if (minSize > sets[i].size()) 
        { 
            minSize = sets[i].size(); 
            smallSetInd = i; 
        } 
    } 
  
    map<int,int> elementsMap; 
  
    // Add all the elements of smallest set to a map, if already present, 
    // update the frequency 
    for (int i = 0; i < sets[smallSetInd].size(); i++) 
    { 
        if (elementsMap.find( sets[smallSetInd][i] ) == elementsMap.end()) 
            elementsMap[ sets[smallSetInd][i] ] = 1; 
        else
            elementsMap[ sets[smallSetInd][i] ]++; 
    } 
  
    // iterate through the map elements to see if they are present in 
    // remaining sets 
    map<int,int>::iterator it; 
    for (it = elementsMap.begin(); it != elementsMap.end(); ++it) 
    { 
        int elem = it->first; 
        int freq = it->second; 
  
        bool bFound = true; 
  
        // Iterate through all sets 
        for (int j = 0 ; j < sets.size() ; j++) 
        { 
            // If this set is not the smallest set, then do binary search in it 
            if (j != smallSetInd) 
            { 
                // If the element is found in this set, then find its frequency 
                if (binary_search( sets[j].begin(), sets[j].end(), elem )) 
                { 
                   int lInd = lower_bound(sets[j].begin(), sets[j].end(), elem) 
                                                            - sets[j].begin(); 
                   int rInd = upper_bound(sets[j].begin(), sets[j].end(), elem) 
                                                            - sets[j].begin(); 
  
                   // Update the minimum frequency, if needed 
                   if ((rInd - lInd) < freq) 
                       freq = rInd - lInd; 
                } 
                // If the element is not present in any set, then no need  
                // to proceed for this element. 
                else
                { 
                    bFound = false; 
                    break; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
  
        // If element was found in all sets, then add it to result 'freq' times 
        if (bFound) 
        { 
            for (int k = 0; k < freq; k++) 
                result.push_back(elem); 
        } 
    } 
    return result; 
}
```

and then in your main (or wherever you need to get the intersection) do something like:

```
vector < vector <int> > sets; 
    vector <int> set1; 
    set1.push_back(1); 
    set1.push_back(1); 
    set1.push_back(2); 
    set1.push_back(2); 
    set1.push_back(5); 
  
    sets.push_back(set1); 
  
    vector <int> set2; 
    set2.push_back(1); 
    set2.push_back(1); 
    set2.push_back(4); 
    set2.push_back(3); 
    set2.push_back(5); 
    set2.push_back(9); 
  
    sets.push_back(set2); 
  
    vector <int> set3; 
    set3.push_back(1); 
    set3.push_back(1); 
    set3.push_back(2); 
    set3.push_back(3); 
    set3.push_back(5); 
    set3.push_back(6); 
  
    sets.push_back(set3); 
  
    vector <int> r = getIntersection(sets);
```

And now you have a vector of the intersection between however many sets you put in. It can be 3, it can be 30,000, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

To get a union of all intersections of sets, it looks like you just need to get all values which appear in two or more of the sets. An intersection is where two sets contain the same value, and a union is the set of all values which appear in "both" sets. So a union of all possible intersections **will include any value which appears in at least two sets**.

For example, with sets `{1, 2}`, `{2, 3}`, and `{1, 4}`, your union of all intersections will be `{1, 2}`.

This should work for any number of sets.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

std::set<int> unionOfIntersections(const std::vector<const std::set<int>*>& sets) {
  std::unordered_map<int, int> flattened_value_count_map;

  for (const auto& set : sets) {
    for (const int num : *set) {
      auto overlaps_iter = flattened_value_count_map.find(num);

      // Count the number of times each value occurs, for every set
      if (overlaps_iter == flattened_value_count_map.end()) {
        flattened_value_count_map[num] = 1;
      }
      else {
        ++overlaps_iter->second;
      }
    }
  }

  std::set<int> unionResult;

  // C++ 17+ required for destructuring
  for (const auto [value, numSetsIn] : flattened_value_count_map) {
    // Include value in the union if it is present in two or more sets
    if (numSetsIn >= 2) {
      unionResult.emplace(value);
    }
  }

  return unionResult;
}

int main() {
  std::set<int> set1, set2, set3, set4;

  set1.emplace(1);
  set1.emplace(2);

  set2.emplace(2);
  set2.emplace(3);

  set3.emplace(1);
  set3.emplace(4);

  set4.emplace(4);
  set4.emplace(5);

  for (const int value : unionOfIntersections({&set1, &set2, &set3, &set4})) {
    std::cout << value << '\n';
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```